# Graph API - Microsoft Groups - Unable to enable these two properties during creation or update/patch

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, office365

Graph API - Microsoft Groups - Unable to enable these two properties during group creation or update/patch.

1. allowExternalSenders
2. autoSubscribeNewMembers

**Error during creation:**

System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --- Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: BadRequest
Message: The following properties cannot be set in the initial POST request. Please set them in a subsequent PATCH request: allow external senders

**Error during Update:**

BadRequest Message: The request is currently not supported on the targeted entity set Inner error:

**Properties Link:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties

**Under known Issues:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#groups this is saying that is true for allowExternalSenders if this is true for both allowExternalSenders  and autoSubscribeNewMembers then how do we enable these two flags for hundreds of groups programmatically. This is hard to believe how Microsoft can have this type of bug or limitation.

**Error Info:**
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: BadRequest
Message: The request is currently not supported on the targeted entity set
Inner error

- AdditionalData:  date: 2020-10-30T17:31:55
- request-id:   04926aeb-8caf-491a-b182-a5b22901df47
- client-request-id: 04926aeb-8caf-491a-b182-a5b22901df47
- ClientRequestId:04926aeb-8caf-491a-b182-a5b22901df47

Comment: Can you repro the issue consistently? If yes, share the detailed request (Graph API call) that you made and response (Requestid, timestamp, errorinfo) that you got

Comment: @Dev System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: BadRequest
Message: The request is currently not supported on the targeted entity set
Inner error:
 AdditionalData:
 date: 2020-10-30T17:31:55
 request-id: 04926aeb-8caf-491a-b182-a5b22901df47
 client-request-id: 04926aeb-8caf-491a-b182-a5b22901df47
ClientRequestId: 04926aeb-8caf-491a-b182-a5b22901df47

Comment: Microsoft Graph team documented this as known issue or limitation. So this won't work for you. That's the reason you noticed that the request is not supported, hence throwing bad request. If you wish Microsoft to consider implementing this as new feature, then file at the Microsoft User voice. Here's the closest one that i can able to find out - https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/32629696-issue-with-allowexternalsenders-property-in-groups. Go ahead, upvote it or file a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Graph team documented this as known issue or limitation. So this won't work for you. That's the reason you noticed that the request is not supported, hence throwing bad request. If you wish Microsoft to consider implementing this as new feature, then file at the Microsoft User voice. Here's the [closest one](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/32629696-issue-with-allowexternalsenders-property-in-groups) that i can able to find out. Go ahead, upvote it or file a new one!!